# What are correct dialogue loudness levels for mixing across different content types?

Tags: mixing, film, dialogue

So I'm interested in what the correct dialogue loudness levels are for different content types.

Assume I am mixing in an environment that is aligned for -20dBFS Pink Noise (single channel) to deliver 79dBSPL/C/Slow at the mix point. It is not a dolby calibrated mix studio but I am using Genelec 2840A monitors with a sub that can be accurately calibrated for monitoring levels.

I am looking for information on correct dialogue levels in:

1. Cinematic Feature - for cinematic release
2. Narrative TV drama/documentary
3. Television Commercial (Op.59 in Australia applies here)
4. Narrative short (web,tv,possibly cinema)

I am generally setting dialogue levels using LUFS meters integrating at around -23LUFS with short-term excursions above this. I am also using Izotope Insight 2 to check intelligibility levels.

Please only answer this if you have specific knowledge about re-recording or dubbing mixing for these types of content.